# Load data infile mysql statement in perl error handling

Tags: mysql, perl

Below is my perl code 
I referred to the following link http://www.tol.it/doc/MySQL/chapter6.html. If there is a better please post.
    use Mysql;

```
my $db = Mysql->connect($mysqlhost, $mysqlDB, $mysqlUser, $mysqlPassword);
$db->selectdb("$mysqlDB");
my $loadQuery="LOAD DATA INFILE '$filename' INTO TABLE $pageURLTable FIELDS TERMINATED  BY '\\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'";
print "Executing $loadQuery";       
my $loadresult=$db->query($loadQuery);      
if(!$loadresult){
  print "Error: MySQl Load failed.System error message:$!.";
  return -1;
}
print "Info:".$loadresult->info"; ## this raises error MySQL::Statement info not loadable;
```

What is wrong ?
Can you suggest a better way of coding this so that Load data file errors are better captured?

Thanks,
Neetesh

Comment: What is wrong, what happens?

Comment: The load file is working. I am worried about the case when I will get rejections as I have some steps depending on the status of the load file step. I want to at least print the output of load file execution. But $loadresult->info raises error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ->do method instead of ->query. 
Make sure that Load Data Inline is enabled in your database.
If above don't work, you can use system(mysql -e "LOAD DATA INFILE...")

Comment: If I use $db->do($loadQuery) I get this error "Mysql::do: Not defined in Mysql and not autoloadable (last try do)...". Also I can't use system(mysql -e ...) as i have further steps to do depending on the status of the load.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use [DBI recipes](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=284436). "executing sql statement" I like to do something like $rows = $sth->execute(); Gives affected rows by last statement, and if rows >0 after loading csv files I'know that I've successfully loaded data in database.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql)
  or die "Can't prepare SQL statement: ", $dbh->errstr(), "\n";
$rows = $sth->execute();
if ($rows>0)
{
    print "Loaded $rows rows\n" if ($Debug);
}
else {
    print "Can't execute SQL statement: ", $sth->errstr(), "\n";
}
```